# Is there a way on aws rds to recover DB to a previous status on an existing instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are setting up a testing environment and required the DB data is always cleaned before test.
I know we could always run a db cleanup SQL to do so. But still, need to spend on maintaining SQLs when db updated.

I'd like to know if RDS provides any solutions to recover an existing instance to a previous status? (like apply certain volume)
Checked some docs on AWS, found restore features but say it can only be applied to new instance.
Any ideas?